# How to pass multiple parameters using ssrs conected to redshift

Tags: sql, reporting-services, amazon-redshift

I am getting this error in ssrs: Cannot add multi value query parameter '?' for dataset DataSet1 because it is not supported in the data extension.
My query is: Select mycolumn from my table where mycolumn in (?)
I tried adding to JOIN(Parameters!Parameter1.Value,",") in dataset properties but it doesnt help.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, many don't accept the multi-value parameters. I had a similar issue with an Oracle database.

You can try putting your query as an EXPRESSION for the Dataset's QUERY so that SSRS breaks down your parameter into text and sends the resulting to the DB.

```
="Select mycolumn From Table where mycolumn in (" + Join(Parameters!parameter.Value, ",") + ")"
```

If your parameter is text, you'd need to add single quotes around it:

```
="Select mycolumn From Table where mycolumn in ('" + Join(Parameters!parameter.Value, "','") + "')"
```

Comment: @Roostam - cool. If you click on the green check, it will let other users in the future find this answer easier - and I get a couple of **points** that are pretty much meaningless (and I think you get a couple for accepting).